# learning-to-rank with reverse label semantics

Tags: learning-to-rank

In the context of popular ranking methods such as XGBRanker, the common definition of the label is a relevance score that is ascending in importance (i.e., more relevant elements are given higher numerical labels). The following text is from the official documentation of XGBRanker:

> For supervised learning-to-rank, the predictors are sample documents
> encoded as feature matrix, and the labels are relevance degree for
> each sample. Relevance degree can be multi-level (graded) or binary
> (relevant or not).

However, this definition has the following issue. Consider a problem in which each query has a different number of items: $|q_1|, |q_2|, ..|q_m|$, and that we label each item in an order of ascending importance (from least relevant to most relevant, starting from 0). Then, for every query the label 0 means the "least relevant item". However, there is no consistent label for the "most relevant item", because in the first query it is encoded as $|q_1|$, in the second as $|q_2|$, and so forth.

**Possible solution:** Consider labeling each item in an order of descending importance (from the most relevant to the least relevant, starting from 0). Then, the most important items are consistently encoded as 0. If this label is used for training, the only consequence is that the most negative predicted scores would correspond to the most relevant items.

**Question**: Is this a valid/correct way to use models like XGBRanker, or is it a strict requirement to label the items in an order of ascending importance?